# How do I connect to a Java command-line tool with the YourKit Java Profiler?

Tags: java, connection, profiling, yourkit

I've build a command-line tool in Java, which I would now like to profile with YourKit.  I launch the command-line tool with something like:

```
$ java -classpath .:foo.bar.jar com.foobar.tools.TheTool arg1 arg2 arg3
```

It runs to completion in less than 2 seconds.

After reading http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/agent.jsp, I tried the following:

```
$ java -agentpath:/home/dspitzer/yjp-8.0.24/bin/linux-x86-32/libyjpagent.so -classpath .:foo.bar.jar com.foobar.tools.TheTool arg1 arg2 arg3
```

...and I get:

```
[YourKit Java Profiler 8.0.24] JVMTI version 3001016d; 14.3-b01; Sun Microsystems Inc.; mixed mode, sharing; Linux; 32-bit JVM
[YourKit Java Profiler 8.0.24] Profiler agent is listening on port 10001...
[YourKit Java Profiler 8.0.24] *** HINT ***: To get profiling results, connect to the application from the profiler UI
...
```

(And then the tool runs to completion and exits.)

I guess (by default, at least) YourKit is designed to only connect to running application.

How should I modify my command-line tool to allow connection from YourKit?

1. I could add a command-line option
   that will have it pause for input,
   and I won't press return for it to
   continue until I've connected to it
   from YourKit.
2. Is there a YourKit API that I could
   add to my tool that would cause it
   to block until I've connected with
   YourKit?
3. Is there a YourKit API or a java
   command-line option that would
   create a profiling "snapshot" that I
   could load and analyze later (after
   the command-line tool has completed)
   with YourKit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to pause profiled application until profiler
"connects"; you simply do not need to do so.

Instead, please do the following:

- Turn on desired profiling modes from startup. For example, if you
  need to profile CPU usage, start either CPU sampling or CPU tracing
  with corresponding startup options "sampling" or "tracing".
  See http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/additional_agent_options.jsp
- If profiled application is short-running, enable snapshot capture on
  exit with "onexit=snapshot" startup option. Later open captured
  snapshot in the profiler UI for analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a YourKit option to do this (which isn't to say that there isn't one), but there *is* a Java remote-debugging option to do this.

Try adding the following to your command line, in addition to the YourKit agent options:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

This should cause the VM to suspend as soon as it starts up, waiting for a debugger to connect on port 8000. YourKit itself isn't a debugger, but an IDE like Eclipse or Netbean will do the job, as will the basic [jdb](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) command line.

So run the command, with both options set, connect YourKit, then use a debugger to connect to the debug port, which will trigger the VM to continue execution, allowing YourKit to get the data you need.

It would be better to do this all using YourKit, but I know of no such way.

Comment: I ran `jdb -attach 8000` to connect to the debug port, and then "run" (inside jdb) to trigger the VM to continue execution.

Answer (score 1):

You could launch it via Eclipse, which has a YourKit plugin that launches on app launch.

Answer (score 1):

YourKit's onexit=snapshot option saves a snapshot file under $HOME/Snapshots on JVM exit. You can load this snapshot into the YourKit GUI for later analysis.
See [this page](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/additional_agent_options.jsp) on their website for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to #3 is yes, there's an API you can use to have your application produce profiling results that YourKit can then examine.

Take a look at the [API docs](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/api.jsp), and also the [Command line tool to control profiling](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/command_line_tool.jsp)

Here's an example of using the API (I haven't tried this code):

```
Controller ykController = new Controller();
ykController.enableStackTelemetry();
ykController.enableExceptionTelemetry();
ykController.startCPUProfiling(ProfilingModes.CPU_TRACING,Controller.DEFAULT_FILTERS);
ykController.startAllocationRecording(false,0,false,0);
YourMainClass.main(args);
String snapshotLocation = ykController.captureMemorySnapshot();
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how either those documented APIs for the command-line tool to control profiling can be used to implement my scenario #3.

Comment: @Daryl what list of available options did you get when you ran `java -jar <Profiler Installation Directory>/lib/yjp-controller-api-redist.jar` ?