# How to profile wall clock time of tests running in maven surefire

Tags: java, profiling, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to profile a suite of tests that are being run from [maven surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/).  I've found related questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096121/profile-entire-java-program-execution-in-visualvm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434860/how-to-profile-application-startup-with-visualvm) nothing quite what I'm looking for.

Can someone recommend a profiler that will let me measure wall clock durations of method calls of the test suite (that is, I'm not trying to attach the profiler to an already-running application)?

Comment: When you run unit tests from IntelliJ it will give you a break down of how long each of those test took. It can read your maven configuration to find the tests to run.

Comment: I'm looking for breakdowns per-method, not per-test, though.  I'm having some success with YourKit.  I'll answer my own question in due course if I figure it all out :)

Comment: So you want to be able to run all your tests in YourKit for example.  Again I would select a suit of tests in the Project window and press the YourKit profile button from IntelliJ.

Comment: I don't have any JUnit suites (is there another way to run multiple tests from intellij?)  I let maven surefire run different tests using @Category annotation.  Also, maven is running tests in parallel which might be affecting execution times.

Comment: If you "run" a package, even your root, it will run everything under it.  I am sure IntelliJ is not the only IDE which can do this, but I don't know the others so well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2566109/150884) has helped me.  I've added the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-agentpath:/home/jshaw/yjp-12.0.2/bin/linux-x86-64/libyjpagent.so=tracing,onexit=snapshot,disablej2ee</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then you can load the snapshots from [YourKit profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/) after maven has finished running.